# How to allow plugins to add views in WPF application while enforcing same look & feel

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, look-and-feel

What is the practice for allowing external plugins to be loaded into my WPF application and add their view (in a specific region), while enforcing some uniform, standard, look and feel.

The question is not about how to dynamically load plugins, but rather on the view and styling aspect.

For example, I wish that each plugin could expose a set of different input fields that the user has to fill (e.g. textblock, textbox, combobox, checkbox...), but I want all views to look the same in the manner of style and behavior. so it won't feel strange to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF allows this by defining implicit styles, which you'd probably want to define at the application level. You can edit your App.xaml to include default implicit styles for any control you'd like. This is done by creating a style without defining a key:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <!-- Default style for all the application's buttons -->
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Of course, each view will still be able to override the default styles, but unless it does so explicitly, it will get the implicit style you've defined.